# May I use a custom segue for non visual purpose?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I try using a custom segue to configure a destination controller for purposes of passing data and injecting dependency.

[Using UIStoryboardSegue for purposes of injecting dependencies and passing data](https://gist.github.com/rizumita/d02427ddbd1d73d6e924)

This way separates a destination controller and configuration code from a source controller.

But Apple's documentation says 'A UIStoryboardSegue object is **responsible for performing the visual transition** between two view controllers.'

Is my usage the right way?

Comment: You want to pass data to it, but not show it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are many ways to solve those problems. A segue is a good way to pass data by calling "prepareForSegue" method. Nevertheless, you don't need it to change data in another controller. If you have some parameters in an instance of a view controller class but not show it, you could just take a reference to it by using something like:

```
let resultViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("result") 
                           as! ResultViewController
```

In that code, "result" is the id of a view controller. No segue is required for that. You could just create a callback for an UI element and call this code to get a reference to that view controller. I think this could be a better solution if you don't want to transition views.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I use this segue in storyboard. I want to know best way to inject and pass data. I want not to refer a DI container's assembler in source controller. So I think the way is better. But I have no confidence because of Apple's document.

Comment: Could you explain a little more the technique you are using? Just looking at the gist is a little confusing. You have no views being displayed by the segue? Is it totally programmatically with no storyboard?

Comment: I set BundleSegue to a segue's class property on storyboard.
The segue connect a button to a storyboard reference.
When I tap the button, the segue performs with executing inject and propagate methods. In the methods, destination VC is injected dependencies and source VC passes data to destination VC.
Finally destination VC appears by pushing with navigation controller.

Comment: In the end you pass data to the destination view controle and then it appears? This doesn't look unusual from what I have seen so far. The segue makes the transition but also lets you pass data.

Comment: Yes. I also think it strange in contrast to using prepareForSegue. But by this code
[sample.swift](https://gist.github.com/rizumita/1c626268a2c61deadcb5), I can abstract a process to pass data using protocol, and can separate the process from controller. In addition, I want to inject dependencies to destination controller not in source controller. If you know an other way in order to using segue for my trial way, please tell me that.